# Run out of memory | Before that: Paste Special method of Range class failed Paste range from different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need two filter a big amount of data in another workbook (wbimport) and copy it into my new one(wbdata). The old list is around 200000 rows long and the new one has about 5000 rows.

My latest error is "Application defined or object-defined error" in following row:

Set rngFilterRange = wbImport.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:EB & LastRowColumnAB")

Thank you in advance!

```
Dim LastRowColumnA As Long
    LastRowColumnA = wbImport.Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    Set rngFilterRange = wbImport.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:EB & LastRowColumnAB")
    
    rngFilterRange.AutoFilter
    rngFilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="GAT", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    rngFilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=arrCriteriaPH1(), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    rngFilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="Y", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    rngFilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=39, Criteria1:=arrCriteriaCN(), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
    'Zeilenlänge ermitteln'
    
    Dim LastRowColumnA2 As Long
    LastRowColumnA2 = wbImport.Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       
    'copy the data of the import sheet
    wbImport.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:EB" & LastRowColumnA2).Copy
    wsData.Range("D1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues  'paste values
```

Comment: ```.Range("A1:EB" & LastRowColumnAB)```

Comment: is it `LastRowColumnAB` or `LastRowColumnA`?

Comment: Ups LastRowColumnA, but after correcting error still occurs